# Finding two solutions to $x^2 - 6y^2 = 1$ using continued fractions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

Can anyone show me how to find the solutions to $x^2-6y^2=1$ by using continued fractions? I know how to find the fractions for $\sqrt6$ but do not know how to proceed. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: $x=1, y=0$ would satisfy

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185971/how-do-i-solve-a-continued-fraction-of-solution-to-quadratic-equation?rq=1).

Comment: Yeah but there exist some other non-trivial solutions where x and y are both positive integers

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555179/pells-equation-through-continued-fractions

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to guess one positive solution, namely in this case, $(x,y) = (5,2)$. This happens to be the smallest positive solution as well. Once this is done, use [Brahmagupta's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity) identity to construct more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are able to find a solution to $x^2-6y^2=1$ like $u_1=5$ and $v_1=2$ as indicated in the answer given by user17762. Then ALL other positive integer solutions $(u_n,v_n)$ can be found by 
$$u_n+\sqrt{6}v_n=(u_1+\sqrt{6}v_1)^n.$$
Thus another solution will be
 $$u_2+\sqrt{6}v_2=(u_1+\sqrt{6}v_1)^2=(5+2\sqrt{6})^2=49+20\sqrt{6}.$$

In general, you can get a recurrence relation as follows:
$$u_n+\sqrt{6}v_n=(u_{n-1}+\sqrt{6}v_{n-1})(u_1+\sqrt{6}v_1)=(u_{n-1}+\sqrt{6}v_{n-1})(5+2\sqrt{6}).$$
Upon comparison you get:
\begin{align*}
u_n & = 5u_{n-1}+12v_{n-1}\\
v_n & = 2u_{n-1}+5v_{n-1}
\end{align*}
This is exactly the recurence relation satisfied by the convergents of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! What if the right hand side of the equation is -1? How should I compute the second solution in that case? Thank you a lot

Comment: @KeyangZhang for $x^2-6y^2=-1$, you first find a solution $(a,b)$ for it and then use the solutions $(u_n,v_n) $for $x^2-6y^2=+1$ to find other solutions for the first equation by using $(a+b\sqrt{6})(u_n+v_n\sqrt{6})$.